# Creating a application in a website

Tags: html, css

If I wanted to create a small program, perhaps a calculator or something, what language would I use, and how would I implement it?

Very new to coding, especially with websites so sorry if it's a dumb question.

Comment: Javascript would do it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a very vague question with so few specifics that it could really be answered 1,000 different ways.

To get you started with your reading though, I would suggest you read up on the differences between server-side and client-side coding languages for the web. That will help you understand what languages you would want to use and for what reasons.

As a general rule though, most people would likely build a simple app like a calculator in javascript, as it doesn't require a lot of interaction with the server, doesn't utilize any data storage, and would run on the users machine rather than tie up resources on your server.

Happy learning, and if you want a lot of responses on this site, you should include more specifics in your questions. Such a broad question is very hard to answer with any sort of brevity.

Comment: Thanks, sorry new to this kind of stuff didn't really know what else to ask.

Answer (score -1):

You can start with HTML, CSS and Javascript. www.w3schools.com is a good source to learn HTML, CSS and Javascript.